# как можно получить прямую ссылку на фотографию, прикреплённую в сообщении?

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

пытался получить прямую ссылку через свойства аттачмента, но ничего, кроме айди фото и отправителя я получить не смог.

```
vk.updates.on("message_new", async (context) => {
  const message = context.message;
  if (message.attachments) {
    const attachment = message.attachments[0];

    if (attachment.type === "photo" && attachment.photo) {
      console.log(attachment.photo); // возвращает только id и owner_id
    }
  }
});
```

в моих планах получить прямую ссылку на прикрепленную фотографию из диалога (photoOWNERID_ID), и вроде как полученные данные должны мне посодействовать, но мешает "ошибка доступа"